# How to choose a file with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a `Browser Dialog` to let the user upload images to my webpage.

I know that I have to use an `<input type="file">` but I do not know where (or better, when) retrieve the information when the user has accepted the prompt that appears when you `click` on the `button`.

In my case, when you `click` on a `button`, the prompt appears and I handle this event via `Javascript`.

Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = function(){ 
  var buttonFile = document.getElementById("buttonFile");
  var file = document.getElementById("file");

  buttonFile.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("file").click();
  }

  var files = document.getElementById('file').files[0]; //I do not know where to put this line
  alert(files);
};
```

```css
#file{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg">
<button id="buttonFile">Upload file</button>
```

Of course, now is retrieving `undefined` because I am trying to retrieve it regardless if the prompt has appeared or not. If I put the line inside the `onclick` event of the `button` it also does not have the info yet. I also tried to create an `onclick` event for the file, but it also does not retrieve the info because it does not know when it has been accepted.

So here I have some questions:

- Where should I put this line to get the value of the image that I am uploading?
- As the filter of the input is not supported for old browsers, should I check it on the server side also, right?
- If I want to check it on the server side (`PHP`), have I to link it to a form?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try putting `document.getElementById('file').files[0]` inside an `onchange` handler on the `<input>` element.

Comment: For 2 and 3: Yes. Actually I'd build this without JavaScript at first, and only when it works add some JavaScript on top of it to make it more user friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got everything right so far, except you don't need to get the value of the files until the user has uploaded them. Otherwise, it will definitely be undefined.

```
window.onload = function() { 
  var buttonFile = document.getElementById("buttonFile");
  var file = document.getElementById("file");

  buttonFile.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("file").click();
  };

  file.onchange = function(e){
     if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.files[0]));
     }
  };
};
```

1) You shouldn't put the line in the onclick handler at all.
2) You're correct in that older browsers don't check for the type. Regardless you should ALWAYS do server side validation.
3) Unless you decide to use web services.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I wanted! A handler for file change :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() { 
  var buttonFile = document.getElementById("buttonFile");
  var file = document.getElementById("file");

  buttonFile.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("file").click();
  };

  file.onchange = function() {
    alert(file.files[0].name);
  };
};
```

```css
#file{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg">
<button id="buttonFile">Upload file</button>
```